# Ruby: Two conditions in Case statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How do I use a case statement and check for two conditions?

I need to check that an item is an array and only contains string classes.

```
a = ['one','twon']  # => ["one", "twon"]

case a                                                                         # => 
when String
  puts "string
when Array && a.all?{|obj| obj.is_a?(String) }
   puts 'an array with only string classes'
else
  raise ArgumentError, "unsupported object #{obj}:#{obj.class}"
end
```

The above code returns the `else` case, when it should be returning the "an array with only string classes" statement

Comment: Sorry, typo, corrected it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditions in a `case` statement are not Boolean expressions; they are values that are compared against the target object using the `===` operator. Of course, any class can override that operator, but the predefined one only returns true for a small set of conditions (like `is_a?`, equals, is contained in, `=~`...). Having a Boolean expression as the `when` condition doesn't trigger a match when that expression is true; it triggers a match when the target object `===` the value of the expression, and for most objects, `obj === true` is not itself true.

So you might want to swap out your `case` for an `if`/`else` chain in this instance:

```
if a.is_a? String
  puts 'string'
elsif a.is_a?(Array) && a.all? { |obj| obj.is_a? String }
  puts 'an array with only string classes'
else
  raise ArgumentError, "unsupported object #{a}:#{a.class}"
end
```

Or do a nested check inside the case condition. But then you would have two `else` states, one for the `if` (meaning it matched the array case but wasn't all strings) and one for the `case` (meaning it was something else entirely). So rather than duplicate the error-handling code like that, I used a boolean variable to indicate when an error needed to be `raise`d:

```
ok = false
case a
 when String
  puts 'string'
  ok = true
 when Array
  if a.all? { |obj| obj.is_a? String }
    puts 'an array with only string classes'
    ok = true
  end
end
if !ok 
  raise ArgumentError, "unsupported object #{a}:#{a.class}"
end
```

Comment: `a.all?(String)` should work too (in a recent ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern-matching!

```
a = ['one','twon']

case a
in String
  puts 'string'
in Array if a.all?(String)
  puts 'an array with only string classes'
else
  raise ArgumentError, "unsupported object #{a}:#{a.class}"
end
```

---

<sup>* ruby 2.7+

** experimental feature</sup>